# Newbie question- Exporting X&Y screen coordinates of a marker to csv or Excel

Tags: coordinates, marker

super noob here, first time posting.

I have a problem which I think you guys will be able to answer easily. I have several videos of an unbalanced disc and what I would need is to extract the vertical motion of a point (that is moving with the disc- glued to it if you'd like) for further analysis. Now I sucessfully added a tracker to the correct point on the disc, and the thing moves with it *yay*, but I'm struggling with exporting of the curves or coordinates of the motion.
Now, I can see the coordinates of the marker in each frame and I could manually write them in excel or something, but that would be time consuming as there are a lot of frames... So is there an automatic way of writing this? Seems easy enough, but for the life of me I don't know how to do it...
Appreciate the answers :)